# how to implement gridview in iphone app which is compatible with ios 5 and ios 6

Tags: iphone

I have implement grid view using UICollectionView which is working fine with ios 6. But when I run it with ios 5, app gets crashed.
I searched for a grid view implementation which can be compatible with both version but could not find solution.

Please suggest me how can I implement such grid view.

Thanks

Comment: check [MMGridView](https://github.com/provideal/MMGridView) and [CHGridView](https://github.com/camh/CHGridView).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with MMGridView but its not working.
Checking with other

Comment: @Developer.iOS  Thanks a lot! I have implemented required grid view with MMGridView with some modification as per my requirement.

Comment: it is pleasure to know your problem is solved....u welcome

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView . You probably only need to make some minor changes to your current codebase.

Comment: Thanks, I am checking it will let you know if face any issue.